# Install button disabled while installing application

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am using PackageMaker 3.0.4 & Mac OS Snow Leopard.

Successfully make setup by PackageMaker for Cocoa Application.

When i try to install application, At Installation type step, install button remain disabled.
I have set User sees to "Easy Install only" and Installation Destination to "System Volume".

So, how to enable the button so i can move to next step & install application.

Answer (score 1):

You mean they're stuck at the screen that says “Install for all users”, right?

They need to click on that.

Yes, even though it's the only option.

Yes, even though it looks like it's already selected.

It's a bug in Installer. The only reason I haven't filed it with Apple is because I have no idea how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I've seen this bug too. I initially thought it was due to 10.6.6, but it seems to happen on 10.6.7 too.

Lame.